# Setting the width of columns that are aligned with the dcolum package

Tags: tables

I try to have a table with some columns aligned with respect to the `\pm` sign. I managed to do that with the dcolumn package.

However, I do not know how to set the columns to a fixed width. How could I create a table like the following one, but with columns 2 and 3 with a fixed with of, say, 3cm?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin {center}
\begin{tabular}{m{2.0cm} D{,}{\pm}{-1} D{,}{\pm}{-1}}
\hline 
\hline \\[-2.0ex]
Runs   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Measure 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Another Measure 2} \\[0.3ex]
\hline \\[-2.0ex]
Run 1  & 12.0,0.2                      & 55,1    \\
Run 2  & 14.3,0.5                      & 101,3   \\[0.3ex]
\hline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end {center}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: don't use -1 use 4.4 or whatever works (essentially that is two width specifications where the units are the width of a digit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second and third column here are forced wider than their natural width by specifying an over-large dcolumn specification so the columns end up being the same width.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin {center}
\begin{tabular}{m{2.0cm} D{,}{\pm}{7.5} D{,}{\pm}{7.5}}
\hline 
\hline \\[-2.0ex]
Runs   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Measure 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Another Measure 2} \\[0.3ex]
\hline \\[-2.0ex]
Run 1  & 12.0,0.2                      & 55,1    \\
Run 2  & 14.3,0.5                      & 101,3   \\[0.3ex]
\hline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end {center}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```